# How to subtract two angularjs date variables

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am fairly new to angularjs, but here it goes. I am able two dates through angularjs in the form `dd/mm/yyyy`, but what I need to do is somehow subtract the two dates to get the difference in days between the two. I created a jquery function to do this, but I don't know how to pass in the two dates to the function. So I was wondering if there was a different way to go about this?

I am trying to set up a trigger system depending on the number of days in between the two dates for certain things to be stylized. For example if it's within 10 days I want it to use **style 1** and if its within 20 days use **style 2** and so on.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Any thoughts on the 2 answers added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also an angularjs novice but wouldn't you handle this by making properties available through your javascript view model?

For example have a *style* field that changes based on the date fields (ie style returns style 1 when if the difference is 10 days) and hopefully through the angularjs binding the updates will propagate to the screen.

I think the right term for this is a *computed property* or *calculated property*

*EDIT*

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but see fiddle for example of calculating date diff and changing a style all based off properties of the view model (scope)

`scope.diff` and `scope.col` are the 2 properties to bind to

http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/wfjv6/

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/0.10.4/angular-0.10.4.min.js" ng:autobind></script>
<div ng:controller="ComputedPropertiesCtrl">
    first date <input ng:model="firstdate"> second date <input ng:model="seconddate"> difference {{diff}}
    <div>when the difference is greater than 10 color changes to green</div>
    <div>eg set the second date to 15/01/2013</div>
    <div style="background-color:{{col}};"> State </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function ComputedPropertiesCtrl() {
    var scope = this;
    scope.firstdate = '01/01/2013';
    scope.seconddate = '10/01/2013';
    scope.data_before = [];
    scope.differenceInDays = function() {

        var dt1 = scope.firstdate.split('/'),
            dt2 = scope.seconddate.split('/'),
            one = new Date(dt1[2], dt1[1]-1, dt1[0]),
            two = new Date(dt2[2], dt2[1]-1, dt2[0]);

        var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var millisBetween = two.getTime() - one.getTime();
        var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;

        return Math.floor(days);      
    };
    scope.color = function() {
        return (scope.differenceInDays() > 10) ? 'green' : 'red';
    };

    scope.$watch('[firstdate, seconddate]', function(currScope,newVal,oldVal) {
        scope.data_before = oldVal;
        scope.diff = scope.differenceInDays();
    });

    scope.$watch('[firstdate, seconddate]', function(currScope,newVal,oldVal) {
        scope.data_before = oldVal;
        scope.col = scope.color();
    });
}
```

CSS

```
h2 { position: fixed; right: 10px; top: 10px; color: red; background:white;z-index:1000; }
input { width: 100px; }
div { margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: well i guess the real problem is how do i calculate the different in days?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray that is great example but how to do it for each item in array ?

Comment: @vittore do you mean that you've got a list of objects like the TODO example on angularjs sites main page? In which case **I think** each child object would have to be a scope object `var newscope = $rootScope.$new();` and then you would use $watch against it

Comment: Right, but how i access those scopes / make `ng-repeat` using this scopes I created ?

Comment: this will give the number of days between two dates, but it doesn't gives the exact number of days on which the time range spreads.

For instance : d1 = 06/24/2015 2PM, d2 = 06/25/02/2015 2PM
the difference will give 2 days
the number of days crossed by the time range will be 3 days

the 2 values can be the same or not, depending on the situation. I believe the 2nd one is more interesting

Answer (score 14):

Basic javascript way:

```
var d1 = new Date('01/16/2013');
var d2 = new Date('02/26/2013');
var milliseconds = d2-d1;
var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
var hours = minutes / 60;
var days = hours / 24;
```

Using one of the Date libraries (such as moment.js):

```
var d1 = moment("01/16/2013");
var d2 = moment("02/26/2013");
var days = moment.duration(d2.diff(d1)).asDays();
```

Answer (score 5):

you simply convert date into timestamp and then subtract.

```
var Date1 = 08/16/2004;
var Date2= 10/24/2005;

var timestamp1 = new Date(Date1).getTime();
var timestamp2 = new Date(Date2).getTime();

var diff = timestamp1 - timestamp2


var newDate = new Date (diff);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) to calculate the difference, using the **amDifference** filter:

> Get the difference between two dates in milliseconds. Parameters are
>   date, units and usePrecision. Date defaults to current date. Example:

```
<span>Difference: {{ dateFrom | amDifference : dateTo : 'days' }} days</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, and here are 2 flawless javascript date functions you should never be without...

```
// Returns the days between a & b date objects...
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    // Discard the time and time-zone information.
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}

// Calculate how many days between now and an event...
function daysTill(e) {
    var eventE = new Date(e);
    var today =  new Date();
    return dateDiffInDays(today, eventE);
}
```

Comment: How to adapter this method to calculate with minutes?

Comment: It's actually calculating the difference in miliseconds, (thousandths of a second) and dividing the result by _MS_PER_DAY to get days. So if you wanted to get minutes, you could just add a variable "divisor" to replace it and pass how many ms to divide, or change _MS_PER_DAY to be ms per minute, or = 1000 * 60 :)

Answer (score 0):

---

**The moment JavaScript library is really very useful and easy to use:**

---

```
var parsedServerOutTime = moment(serverOutTime, "HH:mm:ss");
var parsedServerInTime = moment(serverInTime, "HH:mm:ss");

var milliseconds= parsedServerOutTime.diff(parsedServerInTime) //default milliseconds
var days = moment.duration(parsedServerOutTime .diff(parsedServerInTime )).asDays();// For days
```

**`asWeeks();` `asMonths();` `asYears();` etc etc for more details check http://momentjs.com/docs/**

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one to calculate the total number of days. that days calculate from date to date. so, by default to date is pick the current date.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
      var reqDate = $scope.reqDate;
      let cDate = new Date();
      let reqSent = new Date(reqDate);
      var from = Date.UTC(cDate.getFullYear(), cDate.getMonth(),                    cDate.getDate());
      var to = Date.UTC(reqSent.getFullYear(), reqSent.getMonth(),                  reqSent.getDate());
      let day = Math.floor((from - to) /(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      $scope.day = day; 
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type='date' ng-model="reqDate" id="reqDate">
    <br />

<button ng-click="myFunc()" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px"> Click </button> 
<br />
<b> Total Days :  {{day}}</b> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the below one and it worked out for me

```
var selecteddate = new Date($rootscope.selectvalue);
$scope.firstDate = selecteddate .getTime();
$scope.SecondDate = new Date().getTime();
```

selected date is the one which is selected from calender and it is coming from parent scope. second date will be today's date. later i will find difference using moment diff.

```
var differenceinDays=parseInt(
      moment.duration(
        moment($scope.firstDate).diff(
          moment($scope.SecondDate)
        )
      ).asDays()
    );
```

I am using parseInt because i want to return the integer value only

Hope this works