# Calculating hours difference between two dates in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I've got template which looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="thumbnail">
            <td ng-model="task.id">{[{ task.id }]}</td>
            <td ng-model="task.time_start">{[{ task.time_start | date : 'MMM d, y HH:mm' }]}</td>
            <td ng-model="task.time_stop">{[{ task.time_stop | date : 'MMM d, y HH:mm' }]}</td>
            <td>[here i want the time difference]</td>
            <td><button ng-click="edit(task)">Update</button></td>
        </tr>
```

and I want to count hours difference between `task.time_stop` and `task.time_start`. Is there anyway to do this `"live"`, in template?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298663/how-to-subtract-two-angularjs-date-variables

Comment: Why is this question marked duplicate, the problem is totally different in both.? Strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Moment library for this:

```
moment.utc(moment(task.time_stop.diff(moment(task.time_start))).format("mm")
```

You can wrap this call in a function:

```
$scope.timediff = function(start, end){
  return moment.utc(moment(end).diff(moment(start))).format("mm")
}
```

or even better create a factory for this... to make it reusable

PS: update your code to call the `$scope.timediff` to display the time difference:

```
<td>timediff(task.start,task.end )</td>
```