# from Date I just want to subtract 1 day in javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

with the help of new Date() how i can achieve this.
my code :

```
var temp =new Date("October 13, 2014 22:34:17");
console.log(new Date(temp-1));
```

requirement:

```
before: Aug 4, 2014 11:59pm (EDT)
after:   Aug 3, 2014 11:59pm (EDT)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to specify what amount of time you are subtracting. At the moment its 1, but 1 what? Therefore, try getting the days using `getDate()` and then subtract from that and then set the date with `setDate()`.

E.g.

```
var temp = new Date("October 13, 2014 22:34:17");
temp.setDate(temp.getDate()-1);
```

Comment: this even works with 0 and negatives, perfect, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work well if the new date is the first day of a month.

Answer (score 13):

The simple answer is that you want to subtract a days worth of milliseconds from it. So something like the following

```
var today = new Date('October 13, 2014 22:34:17');
var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - (24*60*60*1000));
console.log(yesterday);
```

The problem with this is that this really gives you 24 hours earlier, which isn't always a day earlier due to things such as changes in Daylight Saving Time. If this is what you want, fine. If you want something more sophisticated, check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Just do yesterday.sethours(23,59,59,999) to get yesterday's date at midnight.

Comment: Milliseconds (1/1000), not microseconds (1/1000000).

Comment: This causes problems in case of summer/ winter time subtractions!

Comment: As noted in the answer: "this really gives you 24 hours earlier, which isn't always a day earlier due to things such as changes in Daylight Saving Time [the US name for Summer Time]". It is, however, appropriate for some uses where just subtracting the day is not.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply subtract one day from today date like this:

```
var yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));
```

Comment: This answer works best as it continues to support methods like `.getFullYear()` without any additional conversions.

Comment: Works for me too. The first answer has a flaw when the new date is 1st of a month and you subtract1-2 days from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract from one date to the next Date. You can do so by clicking on this link for subtracting the date. following this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75394906/12752430).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33810903)