# Convert Date to String in format dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: javascript

I am new to js and I am trying to fiddle with the javascript dates.
I have a following date in the format 01-JAN-2016 and I need to subtract 1 day from it.
I tried

```
var dateVar = '01-JAN-2016'
var d = new Date(dateVar);
alert(d);
alert(d-1);
```

It gives me a date and time in long no. But I want it want it to be '31-DEC-2016'
How can I add the format dd-MMM-yyy to it?

Comment: Please! refer to this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401804/how-to-get-the-day-before-a-date-in-javascript and delete this answer.

Comment: Use some library or do a bit of tweak coding use .getDate() .getMonth() .getFullYear()

Comment: have a look at the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136760/from-date-i-just-want-to-subtract-1-day-in-javascript-angularjs Hope it can help!

Comment: For converting date to format *dd-mmm-yyyy* please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480262/get-current-date-in-dd-mon-yyy-format-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can use **datejs** library

```js
var dateVar = new Date('01-JAN-2016')
var d = dateVar.add(-1).day().toString('dd-MMM-yyyy');
alert(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

or with plain javascript, you can do like this!

```js
var monthNames = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
  "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
];

var date = new Date('01-JAN-2016')
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)
date = date.getDate()+"-"+monthNames[date.getMonth()]+"-"+date.getFullYear()

console.log(date)
```