# Error when subtract date (Can't interpolate)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, calculated-field

Hi i made a simple function to subtract dates, but i keeps giving me an error.

Code JS:

```
        $scope.tosum = function(d1, d2) {

        var d3 = new Date(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
        console.log(d3);
        return d3;
    };
```

Console Error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
{{tosum(timesheet.startDate,timesheet.endDate )}}
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

View/ html site :

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="timesheet in timesheetsCtrl.timesheets | filter:searchText">
   <td>{{tosum(timesheet.startDate,timesheet.endDate )}}</td>
```

I also have tried without .getTime this gives 'Invalid Date' in console

Comment: If you log `d1` and `d2`, are you sure that those are properly defined dates and not some other type of object?

Comment: what timesheet.startDate contains?

Comment: console.log('d1:' +d1+ ' - d2:'+ d2);
output : 
 d1:2015-02-02T23:00:00.000Z - d2:2015-02-04T15:16:01.416Z

Comment: @pankajparkar its a date from mongodb

Comment: on UI, it should `<td>{{tosum(timesheet )}}</td>` JS code `$scope.tosum = function(timesheet ) {

        var d3 = new Date(timesheet.startDate.getTime() - timesheet.endDate.getTime());
        console.log(d3);
        return d3;
    };`

Comment: @pankajparkar still gives Can't interpolate: {{tosum(timesheet)}}

Comment: `$scope.tosum` should be inside your controller..can you add your controller code to your question?

Comment: Got it to work this way ! :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298663/how-to-subtract-two-angularjs-date-variables

Answer (score 0):

Are you using controllerAs?

If you aren't, just write the name of the function, otherwise you'll need to prefix the controller name.

Comment: in same controller, changed to  this.tosum = function(d1, d2) {..... 
<td>{{timesheetsCtrl.tosum(timesheet.startDate,timesheet.endDate )}}</td>

but still same error