# How to subtract some years from current date in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to subtract some years from current date in angular js,
I am trying to validate DOB field, what i see in gmail validation is it is accepting 3 years back from current date so how to subtract some years from current date in angular js

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674721/how-do-i-subtract-minutes-from-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: That's what i was asking i can subtract two date variables but how to calculate it some years back from current date is the question

Comment: And that's what the other thread anwered already, as far as I understood your problem. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers on this question, [How to subtract two angularjs date variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298663/how-to-subtract-two-angularjs-date-variables), that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, below is a pure JS solution:

```
var nowInMS = new Date().getTime(),//get the current time and convert to milliseconds
    threeYearsInMS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3,//calculate the amount of milliseconds in three years
    threeYearsBeforeNow = new Date(nowInMS - threeYearsInMS);//build a new date after subtracting

alert(threeYearsBeforeNow);//voila
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oapo0qed/1/)

---

[Documentation of the Date object at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)